# Flask request and application/json content type

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask, mime-types

I have a flask app with the following view:

```
@menus.route('/', methods=["PUT", "POST"])
def new():
    return jsonify(request.json)
```

However, this only works if the request's content type is set to `application/json`, otherwise the dict `request.json` is None.

I know that `request.data` has the request body as a string, but I don't want to be parsing it  to a dict everytime a client forgets to set the request's content-type.

Is there a way to assume that every incoming request's content-type is `application/json`? All I want is to always have access to a valid `request.json` dict, even if the client forgets to set the application content-type to json.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly that you just want to return request data in a response? How can you make sure you get JSON then?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [`request.get_json()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Request.get_json) and set `force` to `True`:

```
@menus.route('/', methods=["PUT", "POST"])
def new():
    return jsonify(request.get_json(force=True))
```

From the documentation:

> By default this function will only load the json data if the mimetype is `application/json` but this can be overridden by the *force* parameter.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - **force** – if set to *True* the mimetype is ignored.

For older Flask versions, < 0.10, if you want to be forgiving and allow for JSON, always, you can do the decode yourself, explicitly:

```
from flask import json

@menus.route('/', methods=["PUT", "POST"])
def new():
    return jsonify(json.loads(request.data))
```

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing :)

Comment: @RonReiter: Why doesn't it? We take the `request.data` **regardless** of the content type specified by the client. Sure, if the client sent invalid request data (e.g. not (valid) JSON), nothing can be done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters request.data is an empty string when using www/form-url-encoded because it parses it as a form.

From the documentation:

data - Contains the incoming request data as string in case it came with a mimetype Flask does not handle.

Comment: Right, in narrow cases, where a client completely mislabeled the request, the above will fail. How likely is that case, and isn't that true for many other cases where a client malformed the request?

Comment: Is it a bad idea or not recommended to make any coming data to json? I mean always use `request.get_json(force=True)` any where in back-end to extract data.

Comment: @TonyChou: gating on the Content-Type header is one way of blocking bad clients early. If you use `force=True` just because some clients may have forgotten to set the header, then your server will have to do more work (because now all requests could contain JSON and time is spent trying to decode it all).

Comment: This is actually a way to protect your app against CSRF attacks. If someone makes a POST to your app from another site, and your app uses auth cookies that are not `SameSite`, then these cookies will be automatically attached to the request, and without `Content-Type: application/json` header present, the request would be considered "simple" and thus submitted to the server. So this ends up making your app vulnerable to CSRF, unless you check Content-Type (this happens irregardless of if/how you set CORS headers btw, the POST request would still be submitted for a "simple" request).

Answer (score 13):

the `request` object already has a method `get_json` which can give you the json regardless of the content-type if you execute it with `force=True` so your code would be something like the following:

```
@menus.route('/', methods=["PUT", "POST"])
def new():
    return jsonify(request.get_json(force=True))
```

in fact, the flask documentation says that `request.get_json` should be used instead of `request.json`: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=json#flask.Request.json