# Missing form data in request

Tags: python-2.7, post, flask, request

I have following code

```
class MyClass(restful.Resource):

    def get(self):
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
        return make_response(render_template('myfile.html'),200,headers)

    def post(self):
            session['CONSUMER_KEY']=request.form.get('consumer_key')
            session['CONSUMER_SECRET']=request.form.get('consumer_secret')
            render_template('myfile.html')

api.add_resource(MyClass,"/mag/",endpoint="mag")
```

I have written following test:

```
   def mytest(self):
        content_type={"Content-Type": "application / x - www - form - urlencoded","Content-Disposition": "form-data"}
        response = self.client.post(
            api.url_for(MyClass), data = json.dumps({'consumer_key':'testconsumerkey',
                        'consumer_secret':'testconsumersecret'}),
            headers=content_type
        )
```

The issue is form data is blank and thats the values are not getting set in session. When i debug i see that request.data is populated but request.form is an empty dictionary. Can someone suggest how I can send form data in a post request from a test

EDIT: Environment details
Python 2.7, Flask web framework, self.client is . I am using flask.ext.testing

Comment: Could you add som details about your environment? It's flask, right? What type is `self.client` in your test?

Comment: Python 2.7, Flask web framework, self.client is <Flask client>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confused as to what the expected format for the post body should be. Should it be JSON data (which is what you send in the test case), or should it be in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (which is what you claim to send in the test case, and what the endpoint will read)?

If you wish to receive JSON data, you'll need to change the endpoint to read the data from [`request.get_json()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112336/flask-request-and-application-json-content-type). You'll also need to use `application/json` as the Content-Type header in the test case.

If you wish to receive urlencoded post data, then just simplify the test case by removing the Content-Type header and the `json.dumps`. Just pass the data dict to the `data` argument.