# Call web service method on Flask server from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-services, flask, web-frontend

I'm new to frontend development and website development; the goal is **to call a webservice method on a server from web interface (client)**.

**Context**

I wrote a Python web service with `Flask` and I deployed it on my **Raspberry Pi**. I tested it with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and Postman and it works fine, all the methods do exactly what they have to.
I have also a web server (**Nginx**) running on the Raspberry.
The Python web service is exposed on **port 5000**; Raspberry has **IP 192.168.1.4**.
*addWord* is a `POST` operation provided my the web service.
Finally, PC and Raspberry are on the same network.

**Next step**

I want to call a method of the Python web service from a frontend website, a simple HTML page, which I put on my web server.

**My code**

This is the code of my HTML page:

```
<head>
  <title>prova insert</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id='text'></p>
  <script>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://192.168.1.4:5000/addWord";
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(json.email + ", " + json.password);
                text = document.getElementById("text");
                text.innerHTML = 'Ooooooooooooook';
            }
        };
        var data = JSON.stringify({"ita": "neve", "eng": "snow", "descr": "", "pos":"nome"});
        console.log(data);
        xhr.send(data);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import json

import db_connection

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return "Test succeeded."

@app.route('/vocaboli')
def get_vocaboli():
    voc = connection.get_all_words()

    return json.dumps(voc)

@app.route('/addWord', methods = ['POST'])
def add_word():
    data = request.get_json()

    print(data)
    print(data.get('ita'))

    ita = data.get('ita')
    eng = data.get('eng')

    descr = data.get('descr') # opzionali
    pos = data.get('pos')

    connection.add_word(ita, eng, descr, pos)

    response = dict(correct='ok')
    return json.dumps(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = db_connection.DatabaseConnection()
    app.run()
```

dbconnection.py:

```
class DatabaseConnection():
        def __init__(self):
                self.mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user=user, password=password, database='vocabulary')
                print('Connection succeeded.')

        def get_cursor(self):
                return self.mariadb_connection.cursor()

        def get_all_words(self):
                cursor = self.get_cursor()

                cursor.execute("select * from vocaboli")
                return cursor.fetchall()

        def add_word(self, ita, eng, descr=None, pos=None):
                cursor = self.get_cursor()
                cursor.execute("insert into vocaboli (ita, eng, description, pos) values ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(ita, eng, descr, pos))
                self.mariadb_connection.commit()

        def update_description(self, ita, eng, descr=None):
                cursor = self.get_cursor()
                cursor.execute("update vocaboli set description = '{}' where ita = '{}' and eng = '{}'".format(descr, ita, eng))
                self.mariadb_connection.commit()
```

**Output**
[image]

I tried also to do `POST` on `http://192.168.1.4/addWord`, but it returns a `NOT FOUND`.

---

**Question**
How can I call the web service from the Javascript code in the proper way? Have I to use the ngrok tunnel as URL, or I have to use the IP of the Raspberry?
Have I to use **PHP** in some way to work on the server side?
As I said, I'm not familiar with Javascript/PHP, probably the answer is straightfoward but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please include your Flask code and logs.

Comment: I've added the Flask code, I'll add logs ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Flask server is only accessible locally. As per the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#public-server), try specifying `host='0.0.0.0'` when running your app to make it accessible from other devices in the network:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = db_connection.DatabaseConnection()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Then try displaying the `/test` page from a browser on the PC (http://192.168.1.4:5000/test).

If that doesn't do the trick, make sure port 5000 is open on your Raspberry Pi.

Edit addressing the CORS policy error:

Try using the [flask_cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to allow CORS:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

...

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

...
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It works for the /test method, but it doesn't for /addWord.

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of things here:

1. If you are using Nginx then create a upstream for http://localhost:5000 so it can act as reverse proxy and applications is available at http://192.168.1.4 with ssl it would be https://192.168.1.4
2. If backend and front-end are running on different servers you need to use CORS, this could be on [Ngnix](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)/[Flask](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Cors/) level depending on how you have configured.
3. You need to tell flask rather the function that you would be working with JSON content-type for that look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112336/flask-request-and-application-json-content-type)

These steps would sort your issue. Nothing to do with DB if it works using Postman.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the screenshot of the error, and it refers to CORS policy as you suggested. For the first point, how can I do that?For the second one right now Flask is not running on a server, I only started it locally on Raspberry. I don't know what solution of those you suggested is better in my case.

Comment: This is how you create [upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)

Comment: Raspberry Pi becomes the server in this case since Ngnix and Flask are running. Create Reverse Proxy with Upstream of your flask and then add the CORS to the same block at Ngnix (Option 1 & 2) required to fix the issue.